# Typescript code: How to calculate Totale=Sum(Subtotale) and price* quantita = subtotale Angular5

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have this table like in photo. In this I want to calculate function for `price* quantita = subtotale` and to sum `Totale=Sum(Subtotale)`.

[image]

My html code:

```
<table align="center" class="table table-bordered" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Quantita</th>
      <th>Note</th> 
      <th>Subtotale</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr*ngFor="let item of products">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>{{item.Quantity}} </td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<p style="text-align: right; width:95%;">Totale: ALL</p>
```

Comment: why did you remove the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just like in view

```
  <td>{{item.Price}}</td>
  <td>{{item.Quantity}} </td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>{{item.Price * item.Quantity}}</td>

 <div>Total : {{Total}}</div>  //this call the get method Total.
```

For total in component write like below, use this total in view

```
 let total = 0;
 get Total() {
    for(let p of products) {
       total+ = p.Subtotale;
    }
    return total;
 }
```

Comment: I write this function,   Total() {   let total = 0;   let p: any;  for ( let p of this.products) {       total += p.Subtotal;   }    } and in html {{Total(total)}} but doesn't function Can you help pelase?

Comment: this is good solution for me, but in this now I want to change automatic my total when I change quantity or price, Can you suggest me something change? Thnx

Comment: welcome Lonna, even change the quantity  the above code works fine , how you change the quantity value ?

Comment: Thank you, so my Price and Quantity are input value, and I can change it. When I change this value, I want that my total  change automatic

Comment: <td>
          <input formControlName="Unit_price" id="Unit_price " type="number" class="validate" [value]="(item.Unit_price)" [(ngModel)]="item.Unit_price">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input formControlName="Quantity" id="Quantity " type="number" class="validate" [value]="(item.Quantity)" [(ngModel)]="item.Quantity">
        </td>

Comment: i got it lonna, for this your use case you confused with form controls, how they work , your above code wrong i will tell you later(little bit busy now so)..read once  formControls in angular how they work.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  var i = 0;
  $scope.total=0;
  $scope.products = [
   {
     "name": "Product 1",
     "quantity": 2,
     "price": 10
   },
   {
     "name": "Product 2",
     "quantity": 6,
     "price": 8
   },
   {
     "name": "Product 3",
     "quantity": 5,
     "price": 26
   },
   {
     "name": "Product 4",
     "quantity": 10,
     "price": 4
   },
   {
     "name": "Product 5",
     "quantity": 11,
     "price": 7
   }
 ];
 
  $scope.updateTotal = function(){
  angular.forEach($scope.products, function(product){
     $scope.total += product.quantity*product.price;
  });
 };
 
 $scope.updateTotal();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price * Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
      <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.price }}</td>
      <td><input ng-model="product.quantity" ng-change="updateTotal()"></td>
      <td>{{ product.price * product.quantity }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Total</b></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><b>${{total}}</b></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your total for sum(subtotal) is always coming as 0.

Comment: Thank you for your best solution :) I write this function, Total() { let total = 0; let p: any; for ( let p of this.products) { total += p.Subtotal; } } and in html {{Total(total)}} but doesn't function Can you help pelase?

Comment: you cannot do that way

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
 var i = 0;
  $scope.total=0;
  
  $scope.products = [
   {
     "name": "Product 1",
     "quantity": 2,
     "price": 10
   },
   {
     "name": "Product 2",
     "quantity": 6,
     "price": 8
   },
   {
     "name": "Product 3",
     "quantity": 5,
     "price": 26
   },
   {
     "name": "Product 4",
     "quantity": 10,
     "price": 4
   },
   {
     "name": "Product 5",
     "quantity": 11,
     "price": 7
   }
];
 
  
$scope.updateTotal = function(){
  angular.forEach($scope.products, function(product){
     $scope.total += product.quantity*product.price;
  });
};

$scope.updateTotal();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price * Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
      <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.price }}</td>
      <td><input ng-model="product.quantity" ng-change="updateTotal()"></td>
      <td>{{ product.price * product.quantity }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Total</b></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><b>${{total}}</b></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you copy and post as answer